# time.NewTimer vs time.Tick

Tags: go

The [documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Tick) indicates the `time.Tick` leaks ('be aware that without a way to shut it down the underlying Ticker cannot be recovered by the garbage collector; it "leaks"'). I'm assuming this refers to the channel. However, there appears to be no way to cleanup a `Timer`, either: You can make sure it doesn't fire but you can't close the channel (receive only).

The [code for it](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/5fea2ccc77eb50a9704fa04b7c61755fe34e1d95/src/time/tick.go#L45) doesn't contain a `close` call. [runtime.deltimer](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/3792db518327c685da17ca6c6faa4e1d2da4c33c/src/runtime/time.go#L122) (which is the underlying mechanism for `Stop`) doesn't touch the channel either.

No matter what, does `Timer` always leak?

Comment: `time.Tick` leaks because you can't call `Stop`. You can call `Stop` on both a `Timer` and a `Ticker`. Closing a channel is not a cleanup operation.

Comment: Does the channel get GC'd once execution moves past, then?

Comment: Channels are GC'ed just like any other value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only cleanup that matters is performed by calling `Stop` (as mentioned by @JimB).